# CiviDiscount does not auto-apply when filtering on contact type

Tags: cividiscount

I can't get auto-discount to work.  I first tried on my local Civi, and then the demo civi.  As a test, I have a coupon configured on the [demo site](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/cividiscount/discount/edit?&id=1&reset=1) to auto-discount all events for all contacts of type Individual.  Ultimately I need to apply a discount to a member type, but that's not working either so I simplified it to discount by contact type.  Below is a screen-shot of my coupon settings and the price section of the event.

Link to coupon:
http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register?reset=1&id=3
Link to event where coupon should be applying:
http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/cividiscount/discount/edit?&id=1&reset=1

The event is not auto-discounted.

The ideal answer would point out what's wrong with my configs, and fix it on the demo site to prove that your answer works.  Thanks!

[image: Coupon Config]
[image]

Comment: I'll verify this behavior on the demo site .... neither automatic contact-type discounts nor membership discounts are working.  There are comments in the githhub queue about this: https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/issues

Answer (score 1):

This may not a long-term fix, but I found a fix in the CiviDiscount github issue tracker.

The underlying problem:  CiviDiscount source will not apply discounts to events with no coupon entered.

The fix:  Add exceptions so that CiviDiscount will apply auto-discounts even if no coupon is entered.

Here is a link to the fix, hopefully this fix or a comparable fix will make it into the next version release.

https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/98

Comment: Old issue with a couple of [PRs](https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/120), but I still can't get the automatic discount to work.